# Unable to iterate through a json

Tags: python, json

I have a json object that looks something like this

```
[{'"p"': '{"n":"s","i":"1"}'},.....]
```

Just imagine multiple objects like this. I want to iterate through this and access n and i keys like a normal json but unfortunately, i am not able to figure it out.

I tried this -

```
for i in a:
    for j in i:
        j.replace("'"," ")
        for k,v in j:
            print(k,v)
```

But getting this

> ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Is there any way i can convert that weird json into normal json like below

```
[{"p": {"n":"s","i":"1"}},.....]
```

Any help will be appreciated, Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map the keys and values to `json.loads` to convert JSON-formatted objects to Python ones:

```
[dict(map(json.loads, i) for i in d.items()) for d in a]
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/FlawedUtilizedPcboard

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the keys and value of your dictionaries are json strings. You could loop through and convert them:

```
import json

a =  [{'"p"': '{"n":"s","i":"1"}'}]

converted = [{json.loads(k): json.loads(v) for k, v in d.items()} for d in a]
# [{'p': {'n': 's', 'i': '1'}}]
```

If it's possible, it's worth checking to see it you can get proper data to start with because this seems like the source of the data is a problem.